# Regex for extracting unstructured text

Tags: python, regex, google-colaboratory

I would like to extract the following from a pdf:

```
4.72.  text 
4.9. text

4.73.  text
4.74.  text 

a) some text 
aa) some text which has also newlines
like this
bb) some text
a. some more text
b. some more text
```

## 1. Paragraphs

```
 Paragraph_re = r'(\d+\.\d+\.)'
Paragraphs = re.findall(Paragraph_re, text_cleaned, re.IGNORECASE)
```

**# a) Test for subletters specifically**

```
subletters_re = r'^[a-z]\){1,2}'
Subletters = re.findall(subletters_re, text_cleaned, re.IGNORECASE)
#print(Subletters)
```

**# a) text: Text after sub-letters**

```
subletters_text_re = r'^[a-zA-Z]\)(.*)'
Subletters_text = re.findall(subletters_text_re , text_cleaned, re.IGNORECASE)
#print(Subletters_text)
```

**# aa) Sub-sub letters**

```
subsubletters_re = r'^[a-z][a-z]\) '
subsubletters = re.findall(subsubletters_re, text_cleaned, re.IGNORECASE)
#print(subsubletters)
```

**# aa): Text after sub-sub-letters**

```
subsubletters_text_re = r'^[a-z][a-z]\)'
Subsubletters_text = re.findall(subsubletters_text_re, text_cleaned, re.IGNORECASE)
#print(Subsubletters_text)
```

**# a. Sub-letter with point**

```
sub_point_re = r'^([A-z]\.M{0,2})'
Subsubletters_text = re.findall(sub_point_re, text_cleaned, re.IGNORECASE)
#print(Subsubletters_text)
```

**# a. tect: Sub-letter text with point**

```
sub_point_text_re = r'([A-z]\.M{0,2}).*'
sub_point_text = re.findall(sub_point_text_re , text_cleaned, re.IGNORECASE)
#print(sub_point_text)
```

I work in google collab and there are several issues:

1. As soon as I put the ^  sign to indicate the beginning of the line, I get an empty list
2. None of the expressions seems to capture what I want. I tried regex 101 but it did not help me much

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `re.MULTILINE` to make `^` match newlines. Otherwise it just matches the beginning of the string.

Comment: This does not work either. 

sub_point_re = r'^([A-z]\.M{0,2})'
Subsubletters_text = re.findall(sub_point_re, text_cleaned, re.MULTILINE)

returns an empty list

Comment: What is `\.M{0,2}` for? I don't see anything like that in the example text.

Comment: P.S. Use backticks in comments to delimit code blocks.

Comment: Show sample values of `text_cleaned` in the question. You can also use regex101.com to publish test cases.